# Zend_Pdf: euro sign not showing

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, utf-8

I am creating a PDF printer in Zend Framework in PHP that requires special characters to print.

In short, this is my code to test special characters:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$pages = array();
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

$str = "( € ë á ç )";
$strEn = utf8_encode($str);

    $page->drawText($strEn, 20, 630, "utf-8");

$pages[0] = $page;
$pdf->pages = $pages;

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
die($pdf->render());
```

Which outputs (  ë á ç ). The encoding, as shown by `iconv_get_encoding`, shows all  ISO-8859-1. Does anyone know why it won't show the euro sign, and how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

For the € character, you can do

```
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

// Create new font
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_SYMBOL);

// Apply font
$page->setFont($font, 36);

$str = "€";

$page->drawText($str, 20, 630);
...
```